# Does SQL compression of "None" clean up a data table?

Tags: sql-server, compression

I'm experimenting with reducing the storage for a SQL Server database that's over 4 GB and growing. I opened the *Data Compression Wizard* in SSMS, selected compression type of "None" on the largest table, and clicked the *Calculate* button. I was surprised that the result was less than half the original (2.2 GB down to less than 1 GB), even though there is no compression.

Is this a real savings? That is, is setting compression to "none" performing a one-time clean-up of unused space? Or is this a waste of time?

[image: Compression Wizard]

Comment: `ALTER TABLE REBUILD` could remove internal fragmentation so it's possible. I don't know whether or not that wizard takes this into account though.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after testing with a sample database, here's what I found. The important thing is that setting a table's compression to "None" causes SSMS to generate a script like the following:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] REBUILD
PARTITION = ALL
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
```

In particular, note the "alter table MyTable **rebuild**." If the table has been modified, such as dropping columns, there is unused space in each row. The REBUILD option reclaims this space, and the table gets smaller.

So, to answer my own question: Yes, setting compression to "None" is a one-time clean-up of unused space within the table. The resulting savings were not as good as the "Calculate" button would suggest, but still significant in my example.

All that said, a simple "alter table MyTable rebuild" would accomplish the same thing.

*(My thanks to those who posted!)*

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.

Compression Type = NONE simply means rebuilding of the indexes in the table without applying any compression. So, it won't change the Figure. Next time you open the Compression wizard for the table, it will show the same numbers after clicking on "Calculate".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx

Comment: No, it's the same. It rebuilds the indexes, which means one-time clean-up of the unused space withing the table.

Comment: You said: Next time you open the Compression wizard for the table, it will show the same numbers after clicking on "Calculate"... But if it is cleaned up then the numbers will be changed? At least for a while..

Comment: The question was somehow a bit confusing. The compression type=NONE has nothing with reducing space in tables; other types (ROW, PAGE) do have. The fact that REBUILD may reduce space doesn't mean that it's practically always resulting with reducing space. If the index has no fragmentation than nothing will change regarding the space. If there is fragmentation, then one-time clean-up will happen. In this case the reduced space by using compression type=NONE just overlaps with rebuilding the indexes and the one-time clean-up. After that, it has no space-reducing effect.

Comment: There is no point to use compression type=NONE instead of the REBUILD ALL indexes and to wrongly think that by applying compression you'd reduced space. Compression type=NONE is used to return back from other compression types (PAGE,ROW) applied on an index. In that case it will extend the index's space.